# First Javascript program. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I have finally gotten around to creating my first little practice program in Javascript.  I know it's not elegant as it could be. I have gotten most of this code to work, but I still get an "undefined" string when I run it a few times. I don't know why. Would someone be kind enough to explain to me where this undefined is coming from?

```
var work = new Array();
work[1] = "product design";
work[2] = "product system design";
work[3] = "product social media post x5";
work[4] = "product Agent Recruitment system design";
work[5] = "product profile system design";
work[6] = "product Agent testing design";
work[7] = "product customer support";
work[8] = "product promotion";
var course = new Array();
course[1] = "javascript";
course[2] = "mandarin";
course[3] = "javascript practical-Code Academy";
course[4] = "javascript practical-learn Street";
course[5] = "mandarin practical-memrise";
course[6] = "new stuff with audiobooks";
var activity = new Array();
activity[1] = "listen to podcasts";
activity[2] = "chat online";
activity[3] = "Exercise";
activity[4] = "take a walk";
activity[5] = "call a friend";
var picker1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
var picker2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*work.length+1);
var picker3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*course.length+1);
var picker4 = Math.floor(Math.random()*activity.length+1);
var group_pick = function(){
  if(picker1 === 1){
    return "Time to work on ";
  } else if(picker1 === 2){
    return "Time to learn some ";
  } else if (picker1 === 3){
    return "Lets relax and ";
  } else {
    return "error in group_pick";
  }
};
var item_pick = function() {
  if (picker1 === 1) {
    return work[picker2] ;
  } else if (picker1 === 2) {
    return course [picker3] ;
  } else if (picker1 === 3) {
    return activity[picker4] ;
  } else {
    return "error in item_pick";
  }
};
var task = group_pick() + item_pick();
document.write(task);
```

Comment: if you can give a clue on which line u get `undefined` error. That would help

Comment: It's work fine for me . Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/caF2v/.

Comment: Do you realize that arrays are designed to start with index `[0]`?  That isn't the cause of your problem, but is a better way to write code.

Comment: the undefined string is not an error, at least according to the console its not being presented as an error...its being presented as a value in the item_picker() function.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else in the code. Can you provide the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Pro tips: Don't define your array that way. It will be a mess at the end.

Comment: Pro tip2: use as few returns as possible, I would declare at the top `var rtn="";` and then assign values to it and only use one return `return rtn;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array's start with an index of zero. When you assign a value to the `1` index, a `0` index is created you, with no value (`undefined`).

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[1] = 'hi!';
console.log(arr); // [undefined, "hi!"]
console.log(arr.length) // 2
```

Length is 2, check that out. You thought you had one item in that array but length is 2.

Usually it's easier to not manage the array indices yourself. And the array literal syntax is usually preferred for a number of reasons.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('hi!');
console.log(arr); // ["hi!"]
console.log(arr.length) // 1
```

Or just create the array with the items in it directly, very handy.

```
var arr = [
  "hi",
  "there!"
];
console.log(arr); // ["hi", "there"]
console.log(arr.length) // 2
```

---

Once you are making the arrays properly, you can get a random item with simply:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
console.log(arr[index]); // "a", "b" or possibly "c"
```

This works because `var index` will be calculated by a random value of between `0.0` and up to but not including `1.0` times `3` (the length of the array). Which can give you a `0`, `1` or a `2`.

So this `arr` right here, has `3` items, one at `0`, one at `1`, and one at `2`.

Learning to address arrays from zero can be mentally tricky. You sort of get used to it. Eventually.

---

A working example using these tips here: http://jsfiddle.net/du5Jb/

I changed how the arrays are declared, and removed the unneeded `+1` from `var pickerX` calculations.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `.length` attribute for arrays counts the number of elements in the array *starting from zero*. So for example `activity` has elements 1 through 5, so according to Javascript the `.length` is actually **6**. Then your random number calculation will choose a number from 1 through 7, past the end of the array. This is where the `undefined` comes from.

You can fix this by starting your index numbering at 0 instead of 1, so `activity` would have elements 0 through 4, with a `.length` of 5. Also remove the `+1` from your choice calculations.

Comment: Your suggestion, albeit correct, will not impact the *posted code* in any way.

Comment: ok, i figured that and thus started the visible values from 1, leaving 0 blank.  Is that whats being counted as undefined?  If so, what would be the best way to resolve this?

Comment: @GregHewgill In the posted code the author never refers to undefined elements of the array. He even explicitly defines them as erroneous. Go take a look at the code. We miss some part of the code I guess..

Comment: Greg hewgill  Sorry if am incorrect but i thought that arrays are always 0-based even if not explicitly stated.  Am i wrong in this?

Comment: @AminBrodie: You are mostly correct, but there is no way to "explicitly state" that a Javascript array starts at a different index. Simply not assigning anything to the `[0]` index does not change the starting index, which is always 0.

Comment: @AminBrodie You are correct. They are always zero-based, so defining just an element `arr[1]` in an empty array `arr` will result in a length of 2 where `a[0]` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Actually, it's me who is unable to read the code here... `if (picker1 === 1) { return work[picker2]; }` < will in fact *sometimes* produce `undefined` for the reason already stated in every answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you use your "pickers", you don't want to have the `+1` inside of the `Math.floor functions.

Consider this array:

```
var array = [ "one", "two", "three" ];

array.length; // 3
```

The length is 3 -- makes sense, there are 3 items inside.
But arrays are zero-based.

```
array[0]; // "one"
array[1]; // "two"
array[2]; // "three"
array[3]; // undefined
```

So when you add that `+ 1`, you're:
a) making it impossible to pick the first thing in the array
b) making it possible to pick a number that is exactly 1 higher than the last element in the array (`undefined`)

Comment: Note that in the question, the array elements start at index 1, not 0, causing `.length` to be one more than intended.

Comment: i thought Math.Floor() rounds down, creating a situation where unless i add 1, i can have an output of 0 and also not reach the largest number

Comment: @AminBrodie: I think you still don't see the problem. The problem is that the `.length` value that you're multiplying by is *one greater than what you need*. So you're adding 1, which is okay, but you can select the last element of the array and then add 1 which puts it over the edge.

Comment: 0 is still counted in the array, whether you put something in there or not. `var arr = [ undefined, 1, 2 ]; arr.length === 3;`

Comment: ok i understand...yes so if i modify all indexes to start at 0 and remove my +1's in the math functions...i should be good?

Comment: Yes. Even better, just use the array-literal notation (`var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, {} ];`) At that point, you don't need to manage indices by hand at all, anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here as i see it is that when you generate your random variables you're doing PickerX + 1...

So the right way to do it would be PickerX without the +1.
Also Off topic you shouldn't use if commands, try using switch case...

Here's the fixed code-

```
var work = new Array()
        work[0] = "product design";
        work[1] = "product system design";
        work[2] = "product social media post x5";
        work[3] = "product Agent Recruitment system design";
        work[4] = "product profile system design";
        work[5] = "product Agent testing design";
        work[6] = "product customer support";
        work[7] = "product promotion";

var course = new Array();
    course[0] = "javascript";
    course[1] = "mandarin";
    course[2] = "javascript practical-Code Academy";
    course[3] = "javascript practical-learn Street";
    course[4] = "mandarin practical-memrise";
    course[5] = "new stuff with audiobooks";

var activity = new Array();
    activity[0] = "listen to podcasts";
    activity[1] = "chat online";
    activity[2] = "Exercise";
    activity[3] = "take a walk";
    activity[4] = "call a friend";



    var picker1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 +1 );
    var picker2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * work.length );
    var picker3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * course.length );
    var picker4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * activity.length );




var group_pick = function(){
    switch(picker1){
        case 1:
            return "Time to work on ";
        case 2:
            return "Time to learn some ";
        case 3:
            return "Lets relax and ";
        default:
            return "error in group_pick";        
    }
};




var item_pick = function() {
    switch(picker1){
        case 1:
            return work[picker2] ;
        case 2:
            return course [picker3] ;
        case 3:
            return activity[picker4] ;
        default:
            return "error in item_pick";    
    }
};


var task = group_pick() + item_pick();
document.write( task );​
```

Comment: Thanks for that ... also yes i will start to use switches.

Answer (score 0):

Don't work so hard. Zero is your friend. Let's go golfing...

```
var work = [
    "product design", "product system design",
    "product social media post x5",
    "product Agent Recruitment system design",
    "product profile system design",
    "product Agent testing design",
    "product customer support", "product promotion",
], course = [
    "javascript", "mandarin",
    "javascript practical-Code Academy",
    "javascript practical-learn Street",
    "mandarin practical-memrise", "new stuff with audiobooks",
], activity = [
    "listen to podcasts", "chat online", "Exercise",
    "take a walk", "call a friend",
];
function rint(cap) {
    return (Math.random() * cap) | 0;
}
function pick(item) {
    switch (item) {
    case 0: return "Time to work on " +
        work[ rint(work.length) ];
    case 1: return "Time to learn some " + 
        course[ rint(course.length) ];
    case 2: return "Lets relax and " + 
        activity[ rint(activity.length) ];
    default: return "error";
    }
}
document.write(pick(rint(3)) + '<br>');
```